# Conversation history lost between Outlook and Samsung+Android clients

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-365

I recently discovered that, when I exchange emails between my Samsung Android phone (using the [Samsung Email](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.samsung.android.email.provider&pli=1) app) and my Windows laptop (using Outlook 365), the history of previous emails in the chain - which would normally be copied in at the bottom of the email - is frequently lost.  This situation arises quite often for me since, in long email exchanges, I generally use my phone for quick replies but switch to my laptop when a more detailed response is needed.

On investigation, the problem appears to arise because the Samsung app uses the MIME header `Content-Type: multipart/mixed` to separate the current and previous emails, and Outlook chokes on it.  From the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME#mixed) (emphasis mine):

> multipart/mixed is used for sending files with different Content-Type header fields inline (or as attachments). If sending pictures or other easily readable files, **most mail clients will display them inline** (unless explicitly specified with Content-Disposition: attachment in which case offered as attachments). The default content-type for each part is "text/plain".

However, when *Outlook* opens one of these emails, it chooses to always interpret parts 2, 3, 4 etc as being attachments rather than inline document sections, regardless of their file type or even whether the `Content-Disposition: inline` header is set for a given part.  So when I open one of these emails, only the text written by that email's sender shows up.  Any text *they* were responding to is jammed in an attached HTML file with a randomly-generated name... which is then discarded, just like any other attachment, when I hit Reply.

(Some investigation suggests that this is *technically* rules-legal - there's no absolute requirement for MS to support [RFC 2183](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc2183) - but it is a departure from the approach used by literally *every* other email system I've looked at, including MS Exchange!  See my earlier [response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44376271/how-to-compose-multipart-mime-mixed-message-to-display-it-correctly-in-outlook/76795392#76795392) to a SO question for more technical details.)

Conversely, Microsoft seems to prefer that previous emails' contents are just bundled into part 1 of the MIME file, as a single large HTML document.  But there doesn't seem to be an option in Samsung Email to replicate this behaviour.

Can anyone suggest a way I can get these systems to tie up, so that I don't have to keep opening HTML attachments and copying their contents into my replies every time I drop into Outlook?

Comment: I dont see how can change either ends' behaviour.  My suggestion would be to not use Outlook.  I think other mail clients are better.

Answer (score 0):

According to some search, this may be related to the sync settings of your Samsung Email app. You may need to go into the app settings, then into the settings of the email account you have added, then email sync period and change it to all time. You may also want to check the limit retrieval size option and set it to no limit.

Related links:
https://eu.community.samsung.com/t5/tablets/emails-disappearing/td-p/2771746
https://eu.community.samsung.com/t5/galaxy-s20-series/saved-emails-gone/td-p/4443750

If this does not solve the problem, you may try to remove and re-add your email account in the app or use the star feature to mark important emails and keep them in the starred section.

Comment: Bit of confusion here. When I talk about the email chain, I'm not talking about the separate "files" in the mailbox. Rather, I'm talking about how, when you hit Reply on an email, the text of that email gets copied in to the new email, below your signature. (Typically anyway.)

The problem I'm experiencing is that, when the email I'm responding to was _itself_ a reply, the older copied-in content is lost. It's like someone had taken an office guillotine to my email below the second signature line that appears in it.